# Consent Management in Marketing Cloud - Difference between hasOptedOutTracking and DoNotTrack

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, gdpr

I would like to honor the GDPR customer request :

> I do not want Marketing Cloud to track my messaging and online
>   behavior.

For that and according to the documentation here : https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=consent_management_marketing.htm&type=5 *DoNotTrack* functionality is capable of honoring this request for Email. But what about the other channels ?

Also, there is a new REST API route called `/contacts/v1/contacts/id:{contactId}/Preferences` that has an attribute *hasOptedOutTracking* in https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/addContactPreferencesById.htm, what does it stand for ?

For a test contact,  I updated *hasOptedOutTracking* to *true* but *DoNotTrack* profile attribute was not updated accordingly. So they must two be different features.

So here my questions :

1. How to achieve Consent management accross Email, Push and Web
2. What is the difference between *hasOptedOutTracking* and *DoNotTrack*

Answer (score 5):

1. Consent Management across channels is left to be handled on your own.

You have to piece together your Optout process in order to meet your requirements (Preference centers, relational Data model,SQL and Automations to keep your Channels in check). 
As noted in the documentation:

> "Create a mechanism for receiving a Do Not Track request, such as a
>       preference center"

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=consent_management_marketing.htm&type=5

2. DoNotTrack is the attribute that you can add your self to manage your Subscribers privacy and keep them in check with your policy.

HasOptedOutTracking is there by default and part of the Individual object as mentioned in the below documentation link.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.222.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_individual.htm

I hope this was helpful.

Comment: Thanks Bechir, for 1) I am asking about "tracking subscriber behavior" across channels and not subscriptions, DoNotTrack request is only email 2) Yes, but the same field is available as an attribute of a Marketing Cloud Route API. Is it linked to the Individual Object though the MC Connect ? Thanks.